# $\mathbb{Z}$ as a free product of two groups

Tags: group-theory

My question is that can the group $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ be written as a free product of two (non-trivial) groups?
Thanks

Comment: No, since the free product of two non-trivial groups is non abelian.

Comment: @DonAntonio: You should make that an answer.

Comment: There's already one, @nik. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\mathbb Z \cong G\coprod H$, the free product of $G$ and $H$. But $\mathbb Z$ is abelian while if $g\in G$ and $h\in H$ are non-trivial elements, then $gh\ne hg$ in the free product. Therefore, at least one of $G$ or $H$ must be trivial.

Comment: The usual, more widespread notation for *free product* simply is $\,G*H\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio yes, that is the common group theory notation. I guess I'm being a bit provocative by using the coproduct symbol, but, after all, the free product of groups is the coproduct ;)

Comment: If Russian mathematicians were investigated by the KGB for working with "free radical groups", do American (and other capitalistic-world living) mathematicians get investigated when they work with "free products"? :-P

Answer (score 4):

In a free product $G = H \ast K$, $H$ and $K$ are canonically embedded into $G$ and $H \cap K = \{1\}$. On the other hand, if $A$ and $B$ are two nontrivial subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$, then $A \cap B \neq \{0\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Another hint maybe arisen from this fact that if $a\in H,b\in K$ are non trivial elements in $H*K$ then the element $|aba^{-1}b^{-1}|=\infty$ and moreover $H*K$ is an **infinite centerless** group.